# converting array of variable length to tuple in scala

Tags: scala

I need to create a tuple but this tuple's size need to change at run time based on variable value. I can't really do that in scala. So i created an array:

```
val temp:Array[String] = new Array[String](x)
```

How do I convert the array to tuple. is this possible? i'm a scala newbie.

Comment: Is the size the only thing that will vary at runtime? How about the type of the items in your tuple? Will it always be `String` as your example suggest?

Comment: A tuple is by definition a heterogeneous element fixed-arity thing. If you need a dynamic number of strings, you can use any type of collection. Why do you want to convert that into a "tuple"?

Comment: I need a tuple because I need to feed a tuple to another class's method, which I don't have control of. Yes, the tuple is of type String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create a tuple, you have to know the intended size.  Assuming you have that, then you can do something like this:

```
val temp = Array("1", "2")
val tup = temp match { case Array(a,b) => (a,b) }
// tup: (String, String) = (1,2)

def expectsTuple(x: (String,String)) = x._1 + x._2
expectsTuple(tup)
```

And that allows you to pass the tuple to whatever function expects it.

---

If you want to get fancier, you can define `.toTuple` methods:

```
implicit class Enriched_toTuple_Array[A](val seq: Array[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def toTuple2 = seq match { case Array(a, b) => (a, b); case x => throw new AssertionError(s"Cannot convert array of length ${seq.size} into Tuple2: Array(${x.mkString(", ")})") }
  def toTuple3 = seq match { case Array(a, b, c) => (a, b, c); case x => throw new AssertionError(s"Cannot convert array of length ${seq.size} into Tuple3: Array(${x.mkString(", ")})") }
  def toTuple4 = seq match { case Array(a, b, c, d) => (a, b, c, d); case x => throw new AssertionError(s"Cannot convert array of length ${seq.size} into Tuple4: Array(${x.mkString(", ")})") }
  def toTuple5 = seq match { case Array(a, b, c, d, e) => (a, b, c, d, e); case x => throw new AssertionError(s"Cannot convert array of length ${seq.size} into Tuple5: Array(${x.mkString(", ")})") }
}
```

This lets you do:

```
val tup = temp.toTuple2
// tup: (String, String) = (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem.
I hope this helps.

```
(0 :: 10 :: 50 :: Nil).sliding(2, 1).map( l => (l(0), l(1)))
```

Results:

```
List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,10), (10,50))
```