# Spark: How to convert a Dataset[(String , array[int])] to Dataset[(String, int, int, int, int, ...)] using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The Dataset I have has the following schema: `[String, array[int]]`. Now, I want to convert it to a Dataset (or Dataframe) with the following schema: `[String, int, int, int, ...]`.  Note that `array[int]` is dynamic, it can therefore have different length for different rows.

Comment: what's the type of `[String, array[int]]`: `list`, `array` or `tuple`? In title, they are `tuple` type, but in description, not sure what's type for them.

Comment: Do you want a tuple? If so, if there are more than 22 elements in `Array[Int]` you're probably outof luck. If you need it for a method call, you can use the "splat operator", `:_*`. Look it up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682905/converting-array-of-variable-length-to-tuple-in-scala

Comment: not possible in scala

Answer (score 3):

The problem stems from the fact that the tuple `(String, Array[Int])` is a specific type and it is the same type no matter how many elements are in the Array.

On the other hand, the tuple `(String, Int)` is a different type from `(String, Int, Int)`, which is different still from `(String, Int, Int, Int)`, and so on. Being a strongly typed language, Scala doesn't easily allow for a method that takes one type as input and produces one of many possible, and unrelated, types as output.

Perhaps if you describe why you think you want to do this we can offer a better solution for your situation.

Comment: what is your opinion if we can split this into 2 data sets and then map. when we split, we have to add a auto_increment_id or any unique row identifier for both dataset. Just assume there are 20 column in the above scenario

Comment: @Muhunthan, An interesting scenario. It should be posted as a separate question (with code examples). That way more people will see it and you're more likely to get more and better answers.

Comment: I posted in details [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800510/best-way-to-have-nested-tuples-or-nested-columns-in-the-spark-and-filter-by-or-g]

Answer (score 2):

As @jwvh suggest, you probably cannot do this in a type-safe Dataset way. If you relax type-safety you can probably do this using DataFrames (assuming your arrays are not crazy long - I believe currently columns are restricted to Int.MaxValue number of columns).

---

#### Here is the solution using (primarily) DataFrames on Spark 2.0.2:

We start with a toy example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val ds = spark.createDataset(("Hello", Array(1,2,3)) :: ("There", Array(1,2,10,11,100))  :: ("A", Array(5,6,7,8)) :: Nil)
// ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Array[Int])] = [_1: string, _2: array<int>]

ds.show()
+-----+-------------------+
|   _1|                 _2|
+-----+-------------------+
|Hello|          [1, 2, 3]|
|There|[1, 2, 10, 11, 100]|
|    A|       [5, 6, 7, 8]|
+-----+-------------------+
```

Next we compute the max length of the arrays we have (we hope is not crazy long here):

```
val maxLen = ds.select(max(size($"_2")).as[Long]).collect().head
```

Next, we want a function to select an element of the array at a particular index. We express the array selection function as a UDF:

```
val u = udf((a: Seq[Int], i: Int) => if(a.size <= i) null.asInstanceOf[Int] else a(i))
```

Now we create all the columns we want to generate:

```
val columns = ds.col("_1") +: (for(i <- 0 until maxLen.toInt ) yield u(ds.col("_2"), lit(i)).as(s"a[$i]"))
```

Then hopefully we are done:

```
ds.select(columns:_*).show()

+-----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   _1|a[0]|a[1]|a[2]|a[3]|a[4]|
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+
|Hello|   1|   2|   3|   0|   0|
|There|   1|   2|  10|  11| 100|
|    A|   5|   6|   7|   8|   0|
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

---

Here is the complete code for copy paste

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val ds = spark.createDataset(("Hello", Array(1,2,3)) :: ("There", Array(1,2,10,11,100))  :: ("A", Array(5,6,7,8)) :: Nil)

val maxLen = ds.select(max(size($"_2")).as[Long]).collect().head

val u = udf((a: Seq[Int], i: Int) => if(a.size <= i) null.asInstanceOf[Int] else a(i))

val columns = ds.col("_1") +: (for(i <- 0 until maxLen.toInt ) yield u(ds.col("_2"), lit(i)).as(s"a[$i]"))

ds.select(columns:_*).show()
```

Comment: thank you!!! I solved it for you. but what means  ($"_2") ??

Comment: The second column